# How to reindex primary key in tkinter sqlite3

Tags: python, sql

[This is my id number which comes from the database but when I delete a data the index number will not be updated, please help me if there is any solution to reindex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rNII.png)

Comment: Hi, this is not a tkinter related question, it is completely related to SQLITE and maybe python only.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html), I'd say:

```
c.execute("REINDEX <table_name>")
con.commit()
```

where <table_name> is your table name, obviously.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to reindex the primary key which is auto-incremented in sqlite3?

Comment: Hi @Maktum, I think you need to renumber the underlying rowid column in Sqlite. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840855/how-to-reindex-or-fix-rowid-after-a-row-is-deleted-sqlite) for a suggested query, to be run with c.execute(...), substituting your table name for 't1'. Also, maybe try running  [VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) on the table. Cheers, Peter

Comment: Thanks a lot, this information helps me to make what I want.